# What is the notation for a function with unknown inputs?

Tags: notation

How do I refer to a function for which I don't yet know the inputs?

To give some more context, I'm looking to develop a function K that is bounded between 0 and 1 and approaches 0 eventually. The inputs that it will take to achieve this behavior are as of yet unknown though (i.e. it could take the error in the process as input, or the overall score, etc.), so I'm unsure how to refer to the function throughout my research proposal. Currently, I'm referring to it as "K(?)" but it looks off, but I'm not sure how else to refer to the function.

Comment: $K(x)\hspace{0pt}$

Comment: Originally I thought that this would be confusing because it doesn't take an x coordinate as input, but the more I think about it I think this is the best way haha... Extremely obvious in hindsight but I'm going to leave the question up just in case anyone has a similar question.